# How can you deploy a web application onto one of many web servers using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I suspect I'm going about this in the wrong way, but I want to use Ansible to install one of a set of web servers and then install a web app on top of that. I'm having a hard time figuring out what the roles should look like and, in particular, what the app role should depend on.

I can have roles for each of the web servers, but then it seems like I'd have to have a role per app-webserver pair. There doesn't seem to be a way to have the app depend on any web server, or use a variable to specify the dependent role based on my attempts at using one in `meta/main.yml`.

Alternatively, I can have a generic webserver role that itself installs one of the supported webservers, but I'm not sure how that should work and I've been enable to find an example to refer to.

Perhaps I'm thinking about this the wrong way. Is duplication the only way to go about this? (I simplified the problem somewhat for brevity, in actuality I also have multiple databases that can be used, so the combinations would be `m*n` app-webserver-db triplets.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groups of groups in your inventory. Create a main group `webservers`, and subgroups for every application server (`geronimo`, `jetty`, and so on) :

```
[webservers:children]
geronimo
glassfish
jetty
wildfly

[geronimo]
srv1

[glassfish]
srv2

[jetty]
srv3

[wildfly]
srv4
```

And then install appropriate application server according to the containing subgroup. And finally install application on every webservers :

```
---
- hosts: geronimo
  roles:
    - geronimo_role

- hosts: glassfish
  roles:
    - glassfish_role

- hosts: jetty
  roles:
    - jetty_role

- hosts: wildfly
  roles:
    - wildfly_role

- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - application_role
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your problem. But it seems that you can solve this by organizing your inventory properly.

```
[webservers]
srv1
srv2
srv3
srv4

[application1]
srv1

[application2]
srv2

[application3]
srv3

[application4]
srv4
```

You can configure all webservers at once, and then install each application on the appropriate webserver.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - webserver_role

- hosts: application1
  roles:
    - application1_role

- hosts: application2
  roles:
    - application2_role

- hosts: application3
  roles:
    - application3_role

- hosts: application4
  roles:
    - application4_role
```

`webserver_role` would install and configure the common stuff, while `application1_role`, `application2_role`, `application3_role` and `application4_role` would install and configure application specific stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that `webserver_role` needs to install one of multiple web servers (e.g. Geronimo, GlassFish, Jetty, WildFly, various others). There's only one application, but there are several web servers it can be deployed to (and the same for databases). That's the part I'm trying to figure out, I can't have `application_role` depend on a variable `{{ webserver_role }}`, that doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. I understood the wrong way. Take a look at my second answer.